# Split characters and numbers in a string with whitespace

Tags: python

Suppose I have this variable

`row1 = 'Other Middle East 368 102 31 29 162 54 0.0 -56.0'`

`row2 ='United Arab Emirates 248 689 42 23 754 243 0.0 204.0'`

How can I get the countries out into a list like below?

`country = ['Other Middle East','United Arab Emirates']`

Great thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to use regex. `\D` will match non digit characters, and `\d` will match digit characters.

```
import re

row1 = 'Other Middle East 368 102 31 29 162 54 0.0 -56.0'
row2 ='United Arab Emirates 248 689 42 23 754 243 0.0 204.0'
row3 = 'ASEAN (South) 248 689 42 23 754 243 0.0 204.0'

print(re.findall('(\D+?) \d', row1 + row2 + row3))
```

Output

```
['Other Middle East', 'United Arab Emirates', 'ASEAN (South)']
```

Comment: Hi alec, many thanks for your answer. A quick question: what if in the country name, there is a parenthesis (e.g. 'ASEAN (South)' )?